# JWT in Spring Security app always return a 403 error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I'm get a 403 error **always** when I'm using JWT in Spring Security.

Full code of my project on GitHub: https://github.com/gavrilovegor519/SocialAPI.

This problem arises only on authenticated endpoints (hasRole or authenticated methods).

My code:

JwtAuthenticationFilter.java

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthenticationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtUtilities jwtUtilities;
    private final UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
                                    @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
                                    @NonNull FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        String token = jwtUtilities.getToken(request);

        if (token != null && jwtUtilities.validateToken(token)) {
            String username = jwtUtilities.extractUsername(token);

            UserDetails userDetails = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
            if (userDetails != null) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication =
                        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails.getUsername(), null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                log.info("authenticated user with username :{}", username);
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

            }
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

}
```

JwtUtilities.java

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class JwtUtilities {


    @Value("${jwt.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("${jwt.expiration}")
    private Long jwtExpiration;


    public String extractUsername(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getSubject);
    }

    public Claims extractAllClaims(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody();
    }

    public <T> T extractClaim(String token, Function<Claims, T> claimsResolver) {
        final Claims claims = extractAllClaims(token);
        return claimsResolver.apply(claims);
    }

    public Date extractExpiration(String token) {
        return extractClaim(token, Claims::getExpiration);
    }

    public Boolean validateToken(String token, UserDetails userDetails) {
        final String username = extractUsername(token);
        return (username.equals(userDetails.getUsername()) && !isTokenExpired(token));
    }

    public Boolean isTokenExpired(String token) {
        return extractExpiration(token).before(new Date());
    }

    public String generateToken(String username, List<String> roles) {

        return Jwts.builder().setSubject(username).claim("role", roles).setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
                .setExpiration(Date.from(Instant.now().plus(jwtExpiration, ChronoUnit.MILLIS)))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret).compact();
    }

    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token);
            return true;
        } catch (SignatureException e) {
            log.info("Invalid JWT signature.");
            log.trace("Invalid JWT signature trace: {}", e);
        } catch (MalformedJwtException e) {
            log.info("Invalid JWT token.");
            log.trace("Invalid JWT token trace: {}", e);
        } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
            log.info("Expired JWT token.");
            log.trace("Expired JWT token trace: {}", e);
        } catch (UnsupportedJwtException e) {
            log.info("Unsupported JWT token.");
            log.trace("Unsupported JWT token trace: {}", e);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            log.info("JWT token compact of handler are invalid.");
            log.trace("JWT token compact of handler are invalid trace: {}", e);
        }
        return false;
    }

    public String getToken(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        final String bearerToken = httpServletRequest.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (StringUtils.hasText(bearerToken) && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7, bearerToken.length());
        } // The part after "Bearer "
        return null;
    }

}
```

UserDetailsServiceImpl.java

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepo userRepository;

    public UserDetailsServiceImpl(UserRepo userRepository) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepository.findUserByUsername(username);
        if (user == null)
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Invalid username or password.");

        return user;
    }

}
```

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final JwtAuthenticationFilter jwtAuthenticationFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
                .sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authHttp -> authHttp
                        .requestMatchers("/reg", "/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/user/**")).hasRole("USER")
                        .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/admin/**")).hasRole("ADMIN"));

        http.addFilterBefore(jwtAuthenticationFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

}
```

P.S.: I have a trace log of Spring Security:

```
2023-05-31T11:28:03.744+03:00 DEBUG 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /user/users/all?first=1&last=5
2023-05-31T11:28:03.744+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.745+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.745+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.745+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.745+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.745+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-05-31T11:28:03.746+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JwtAuthenticationFilter (6/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.789+03:00  INFO 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] c.e.s.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter   : authenticated user with username :gavrilovegor519
2023-05-31T11:28:03.790+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-05-31T11:28:03.790+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.791+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.791+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.791+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.792+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=gavrilovegor519, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=null, Granted Authorities=[com.egor.socialapi.entities.Role@313bc521]]
2023-05-31T11:28:03.792+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Preparing session with ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy (1/1)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.792+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.792+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.793+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@27712150]
2023-05-31T11:28:03.798+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@27712150] using AuthorityAuthorizationManager[authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
2023-05-31T11:28:03.798+03:00 DEBUG 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Secured GET /user/users/all?first=1&last=5
2023-05-31T11:28:03.811+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
2023-05-31T11:28:03.816+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@1814d559, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@318ec9a7, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@f0fc41b, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7673507f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@71d11ac5, com.egor.socialapi.security.JwtAuthenticationFilter@22c3372b, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@51bda2eb, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@1088048a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@f7a36da, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@b22c65a, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@2e9b19f0, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@455acd0]] (1/1)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.816+03:00 DEBUG 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /error?first=1&last=5
2023-05-31T11:28:03.816+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.816+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.817+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.817+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.817+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (5/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.817+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Or [Ant [pattern='/logout', GET], Ant [pattern='/logout', POST], Ant [pattern='/logout', PUT], Ant [pattern='/logout', DELETE]]
2023-05-31T11:28:03.817+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking JwtAuthenticationFilter (6/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.817+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking RequestCacheAwareFilter (7/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.817+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (8/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.817+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (9/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.817+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SessionManagementFilter (10/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.817+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (11/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.818+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking AuthorizationFilter (12/12)
2023-05-31T11:28:03.818+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationHttpRequest@2279a02b]]
2023-05-31T11:28:03.821+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager : Denying request since did not find matching RequestMatcher
2023-05-31T11:28:03.823+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext : Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
2023-05-31T11:28:03.823+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : Set SecurityContextHolder to AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]]
2023-05-31T11:28:03.823+03:00 TRACE 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Sending AnonymousAuthenticationToken [Principal=anonymousUser, Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_ANONYMOUS]] to authentication entry point since access is denied

org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access Denied
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:98) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:91) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.0.jar:6.1.0]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:101) ~[spring-web-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:642) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:410) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:277) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:358) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:222) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:390) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.8.jar:10.1.8]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

2023-05-31T11:28:03.829+03:00 DEBUG 9064 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.s.w.a.Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint     : Pre-authenticated entry point called. Rejecting access
```

Comment: You have to permit `/error` to see the real problem. Something went wrong with `/user/users/all?first=1&last=5`.

Comment: Now 404. So the problem is not in Spring Security.

Comment: Yes, your endpoints are not there. Show your controller method  for that endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

I allowed "/error", and I realized that the problem is not in the security code, but in the controllers. I will check the controllers. Thanks, @dur.

Answer (score 0):

```
 authentication.setDetails(
                    new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request)
            );
```

Comment: Answers seems legit, would suggest to explain why it works and if this is a workaround or a standard practice.